# SQL jobs aren't keeping log or history

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 where multiple jobs are running , however for none of the agents job history is available.

it's like it isn't recording and job history of anything.

> Even the sysjobhistory TABLE IS EMPTY WITH NO RECORDS IN SIDE

I tried increasing the limit in agent properties (Didn't work)
tried multiple things without any success

Comment: Have you tried these? 1. Uncheck the Limit size of Job history log. 2. Uncheck the "Remove agent history"

Comment: yes I tried all of that

Comment: Can you try finding for SQL Log related errors form the SQL Error Logs? To find error log file location:  `USE MASTER  
GO  
EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Logging SQL Server messages in file'
GO`

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart `SQL Agent Service`. After updating your `SQL Server Agent -> History`

[image]

Comment: I tried that but still not working, it's not recording from the start the table is empty and in sql agent settings the log isn't deleted